# Is it possible to run a Rails app and React app on the same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, content-management-system, single-page-application, api-design

I have a scenario where I want to build a site which would serve as a CMS and social network. All along I would be using Rails only as my API provider. I was originally going to do the client side entirely in React with Redux but as the build grew I found myself writing tons of boilerplate for the most simple tasks (CMS wise).

Instead of going through with the build I thought it would be best to build out the CMS using Rails being that you get your CRUD based tools right of the box. At this point I would have the API and CMS in the same Rails app.

The social network aspect of writing posts, creating collections, etc. would still be done using React. I was wondering if it were at all possible to accomplish a scenario where I could separately make a Rails app and SPA under the same domain. Any resources would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I'm aware there's a React gem for rails but would rather use it as a standalone to take advantage of using Redux and other Node packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a reverse proxy like Nginx. Nginx allows you to map different paths to different hosts or same host (with different ports)

```
location /cms/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:3000;
   }

location /social/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:3100;
}
```

You can find more information in the following URL

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: This is the best solution. When using NGINX you can run many apps on different environments and ports, and with the reverse proxy you are able to  redirect the incoming traffic to the correct app.